# getting Spring webservice error Invalid request[UnmarshallingFailureException]

Tags: exception, jaxb, unmarshalling, spring-ws

I am trying to call a spring web service but i am getting the following exception

```
org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: Invalid request[UnmarshallingFailureException]
```

Here is my spring configuration

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
                    ...
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd">

    <util:list id="packagesToScanList" list-class="java.util.ArrayList">
        <value>webservice.messages.lmsapi.serviceoperations</value>
        <value>webservice.messages.lmsapi.types.user</value>
        <value>webservice.messages.lmsapi.types.customer</value>
        <value>webservice.messages.lmsapi.types.enrollment</value>
        <value>webservice.messages.lmsapi.types.orggroup</value>
        <value>webservice.messages.lmsapi.types.securityroles</value>
        <value>webservice.messages.lmsapi.types.trainingplan</value>
        <value>webservice.messages.lmsapi.types.usergroup</value>
        <value>org.w3._2001.xmlschema</value>
    </util:list>

    <!-- Configure Spring Web Services -->
    <bean id="lmsApiWebServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate"
        p:defaultUri="${lmsapi.uri}"
        p:marshaller-ref="lmsApiJaxbMarshaller"
        p:unmarshaller-ref="lmsApiJaxbMarshaller" />

    <bean id="lmsApiJaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller"
        p:packagesToScan-ref="packagesToScanList"/>
```

Here how i am calling this

```
public AddUserResponse createUser(AddUserRequest addUserRequest) {

    System.out.println();
    JAXBElement<AddUserResponse> response = (JAXBElement<AddUserResponse>)lmsApiWebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(addUserRequest);
    AddUserResponse addUserResponse = (AddUserResponse)response.getValue();
    return addUserResponse;
}
```

In the debug console it is print that

```
[org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent] - Sent request [SaajSoapMessage {http:/webservice/message/lmsapi/serviceoperations}AddUserRequest]
[org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.received] - Received response     [SaajSoapMessage {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Fault] for request [SaajSoapMessage {http://webservice/message/lmsapi/serviceoperations}AddUserRequest]
[org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate] - Received Fault message for request [SaajSoapMessage {http://webservice/message/lmsapi/serviceoperations}AddUserRequest]
```

It means webservice is calling

Why i am getting this unmarshalling error? Is there any way i see the request that spring is sending and receiving and exactly where i am getting this exception?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unmarshalling error is wrapped in a SOAP Fault. As such, it is occurring on the *server-side*, not the client-side. You should check the server-side logs to see what's going on there.

As for your question regarding logging: the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/reference/html/common.html#logging) shows you how.

Comment: Ah thanks. I did the logging and then i saw the SOAP request that I was sending. Then I matched that request with request that SOAPUI creates. Then I noticed that I was not setting the one mandotory element while creating user which is password. That's why i was getting the unmarshalling error. After setting that variable everything going to work fine. Thanks for your help buddy ;) :)